# opencart additional thumbnail to category

Tags: php, image, opencart

I am trying to add an extra image in admin of Opencart category. Following is the structure that i have placed through category_form.tpl. It is uploading image to the image/cache but once i save and open category its not showing my 2nd thumb image. It remain the same for both of the images.

Please save my day with proper guide. Thanks
[image: image of admin panel add new category]

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: to many files are involved to add category 2nd image.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to add new image into the category but want to show it in front end.
Kindly advince

[image: able to add 2nd image to category]

Comment: done with adding new thumb or image with coding and able to show them in different pages. thanks